# SE.com/questions/custom gone?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange

**Where did the custom page go?**

[image]

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6711/se-questions-custom-gone-closed) on Meta.StackExchange, because... well it's a question about a now missing StackExchange feature. I was told to post it here... so... here we go again:

My hotbar link to https://stackexchange.com/questions/custom stopped working. stackexchange.com/questions still works, but it doesn't have the options on the right to filter out topics I don't like (English, OnStartups, etc) while keeping those I do like (SO, Programmers, etc).

While I do like the "Tags" portion, I use it **FAR** less than /Custom for the simple fact that I don't like limiting the searches to tags. I've ran across many questions that don't have tags I'd have thought of listing. I do have [this tagset](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/115/programmer) BUT the layout and feel between this and what custom had is different...

Is it permanent that I can't filter SE by site now? On purpose? Chance of getting it back? Bug? "Feature"?

Edit: Question is about SE. Not SO. Corrected typo.

Comment: I'm really annoyed that this has stopped working, I'd use it a few times a day just to see a range of interesting questions. Was great to be able to filter out sites for which I have absolutely no interest. Given that I can't find any mention of it being removed anywhere it seems like it's a bug or mistake...

Comment: My point exactly. I've made a tagged set of "all questions" for various sites, but it just doesn't have the same ambiance.

Comment: To explain the point about here versus Meta Stack Exchange - Meta Stack Exchange is for the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites like MathOverflow. Here is where you ask about the Stack Exchange Network and Stack Exchange 2.0, which is where http://stackexchange.com/ is. It is confusing, yes, but hopefully this clarifies it for you in the future.

Comment: @Grace Still confused but I'll take your word for it, as someone said more or less the same thing on my M.SE question. More pressing is the /custom feature missing... THAT is something I actually miss and want back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our tracking indicated that almost no one used this page, and it seemed like tagsets had generally superseded it, so we decided to remove it.

Note that you can add an entire site to a tagset (by clicking the little "add entire site" link).  The main difference is that that will show you every new question on a site, rather than only the hottest questions.

If enough users want the feature back, we can always undo the decision.

Comment: Would it be possible to add "hottest" as a criteria/selection for tagsets? "Unanswered"? "Featured"? Give back the option that was lost (and maybe more options)? I'm okay with the idea of tagsets... I think they just need more options. "all" vs "featured" vs unanswered". That would be an awesome addition that would make tagsets more useable for me, personally. Unanswered questions for "these" sites, hot questions from "those" sites... That's what I gravitate towards.

Comment: The problem with only showing new questions is that StackOverflow overwhelms everything else. Then if I had a custom tagset of "sites I'm interested in except for StackOverflow", SuperUser would probably be dominant, etc. Whatever algorithm you used was working perfectly as I always got a good mix of interesting questions from all the sites I was interested in. Please either bring it back or provide a "hottest" option for tagsets!

Comment: Yeah... I'd be happy if Tag-sets had an option to limit an "Add all from site" to Popular, Unanswered, etc. So you could include "StackOverflow#Popular" instead of just "StackOverflow". I'd just like the same functionality (or better if tags is customizable).  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81186/tagged-questions-needs-more-options-popular-unanswered-bounty-etc

Comment: @jwaddell @wernerCD since this question is essentially answered, can you open a new [feature-request] so people can vote on it and continue discussion there?