# "Tagged Questions" needs more options: Popular, Unanswered, Bounty, etc

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, tag-filters

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79690/se-com-questions-custom-gone) about meta.SO.com/Questions/custom disappearing due to lack of popularity has me perplexed.

I don't mind Tagsets... It's a good idea, but I think it is lacking in options. They don't have the "option" that I've grown to like. Basically I prefer the "Popularity" option for sites I like. It's the main reason I haven't used tag-sets before...

Which makes me think that what would make Tagset *THAT* much better (and a real option for me)... is the same options that are available on the individual sites: Popular, Hot, Unanswered, week, month, etc

I'd think something added to Tagset under "Add an entire site" with the option to get the subset of that site... Like "StackOverflow#Popular", "Webmasters#Unanswered", etc. Instead of "All Questions" it'd be "Popular", "Hot", whatever...

Just a thought... Agree/Disagree?